# discord.py bot can't DM users

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am writing a Discord Bot in python using discord.py. I have a ban command to ban other users and send them a Direct Message informing them about their ban. I can't seem to get it to work.

```
The script looks like this:

`import discord
from discord.ext import commands

print("Powerup initiated!")

print("Setting command prefix and intents")

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
intents.dm_messages = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="/help"))
    print(f"{client.user} has connected to Discord!")
    print("Powerup complete!")
    print("--------------------------")

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Bot's up and running!")

@client.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    try:
        dm_message = f'You have been banned from {ctx.guild} for {reason}.'
        await member.send(dm_message)
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send(f"Couldn'd DM {member.mention}. {member.mention} has been banned without a DM.")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has been banned and informed in his DMs.')

client.run('The Token of my bot')`
```

I tried using my normal !ban command on my alt and it SHOULD have banned him with a dm because it is a fresh account with default settings. However, my alt doesn't get a DM and the bot tells me it couldn't send a DM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because the bot bans them before sending the DM. Try moving the `await member.ban(reason=reason)` to the bottom of your command.

Answer (score 0):

**1st:** Go to your discord bot's developer portal applications
https://discord.com/developers/applications/(application id)/information

**2nd:** Ensure that all 3 of the following are turned on
[Privileged intents are necessary for the bot to message your guild members](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxms8.png)

**Side note:** If by some reason the above method didn't work, double check that you have the required Text Permission enabled under the ***Bot permissions*** section. To rule out this variable, enable administrator access in the [discord bot permissions calculator](https://discordapi.com/permissions.html) and reinvite the bot to your server.